# How to add public permissions for S3 bucket via terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform

I am creating a s3 bucket using below terraform template, and want to apply some(2 out of 4) public permissions for the bucket, please suggest how can we do that.

Terraform template for s3 bucket :

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "example" {
  bucket = "example"
}
```

Now I want to tick out 2 permissions which are there on the AWS console s3 bucket permissions :

I want to apply those 2 permissions to my bucket

Please suggest any way how can we achieve this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to use [aws_s3_bucket_public_access_block](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/s3_bucket_public_access_block). For example:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "example" {
  bucket = "example"
}


resource "aws_s3_bucket_public_access_block" "example" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.example.id

  block_public_acls   = false
  block_public_policy = false
}
```

The above are bucket-level settings. There are also account level settings which you can change using [aws_s3_account_public_access_block](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/s3_account_public_access_block).

Comment: Does these block_public_acls and block_public_policy, corresponds to the ones which i ticked out in the screenshot? Got confused in that

Comment: @Legitimate_Figure_4430 Yes, they do match.

Comment: Why isn't `block_public_acls = false`? Seems like the logic should be inverse.

Comment: block_public_acls/policy should be false to allow for public access. Answer edited.

Comment: Why do you explicitly have to define `block_public_policy = false` even though it defaults to that value? 
Every argument in the `s3_bucket_public_access_block` [resource](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/s3_bucket_public_access_block) is not only optional but it also defaults to `False`, which to me suggests that you either don't have to define any argument or omit the whole resource whatsoever